# How to create a behavior for a Picker using MVVM on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a behavior to my ViewModel. So what I did was, Create a class behavior for a Picker and create a BindableProperty so I could fill my property from the ViewModel, but it's not working.

```
public class PickerItemsBehavior : Behavior<Picker>
{
    static readonly BindablePropertyKey Item = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("ItemSource", typeof(string), typeof(PickerItemsBehavior), false);

    public static readonly BindableProperty Items = Item.BindableProperty;

    public Picker MyPicker { get; set; }

    public string ItemSource
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(Items); }
        private set { SetValue(Items, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Picker bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        MyPicker = bindable;
        MyPicker.Items.Add(ItemSource);

    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Picker bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Picker Title="select">
    <Picker.Behaviors>
      <behaviors:PickerItemsBehavior ItemSource="{Binding Item}"/>
    </Picker.Behaviors>
  </Picker>
```

And in my ViewModel i just set a string property return a string..

Comment: I'm having problems creating a behavior for the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Me too.. any luck